# Get the String content from a Text() Widget in Flutter

Tags: android, text, dart, flutter

Is it possible to get the `String` value from a `Text()` Widget after it is defined?

**Example code**

```
Text txt = Text("example text");

getValueFromtxt() {
  var value = txt.text;                  <------
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return txt;
}
```

Comment: That code smells, you are probably doing something wrong. In 99.9999% of all cases, there should be no need to read a property from a defined widget.

Comment: My code is just an example on how you could get the value from the widget and could you explain why there is no need to read a property from a defined widget? You could use it to set it to a different value. We can all learn from eachother!

Comment: Widgets should be (and the default widgets are) immutable. To change the value of a widget, you just trigger a rebuild of the enclosing widget (that's what the `build` method is for), usually by calling `setState` in one of the parent widgets. It's the same technique that powers the React framework.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not that difficult I had to use `Text().data`:

```
Text txt = Text("example text");

getValueFromtxt() {
  var value = txt.data;                  <------
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@FoxyError you can do that as above answer but You can Avoid that by just storing value in String variable.

```
String string = "hello World";
```

You can use it to print or change the value.

```
 new Text("Any String" + string);
```

Comment: Ofcourse that's true my example didn't really represent the situation I really had. The Text() Widget came from another method in another class. But thanks, your answer could solve someone elses problem.