# I need to add data of three Text

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get data form three text and text should not be editable and show the addiction of three text in different text. 
how should i do this.This is my code. how should i get data in some string or int value like in android java file we have textview.gettext(); how that done in flutter. i just simply need to get the value from three text and add theme without click on button and show in different text.

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _counter = 0;
  double _first=11.22;
  double _second=11.22;
  double _Third=11.22;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
              Row(
              children: <Widget>[

                SizedBox(width: 60.0),
                Text(
                  'Item Cost :-',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 90.0),
                Text(
                  '\u20B9 $_first',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 60.0),
                Text(
                  'Delary charges  :-',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 40.0),
                Text(
                  '\u20B9 $_second',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 60.0),
                Text(
                  'GST :-',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 140.0),
                Text(
                  '\u20B9 $_Third',
                  style: TextStyle(

                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 60.0),
                Text(
                  'Total Price :-',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 80.0),
                Text(
                  '\u20B9 $_counter ',
                  style: TextStyle(

                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: RawMaterialButton(
        fillColor: Colors.green,
        splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20.0,
              vertical: 8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,),
              SizedBox(width: 8.0,),
              Text("Add", style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
              ),),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
        onPressed: () {
          print("pressed");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51949194/6709477)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use text controller for getting data from those three textview and then use a var type to store all three text values,than at the end in 4'th textview call that var store value for displaying the result.

Comment: @ Rahul Singh Thanks it works how to  add a string var  which have the addition of two other var with out button press event.

Comment: make a method which runs when you open your routes.put this method in your initState() and get the string value from those textviews and i think you batter know how to add two strings.