# Getting Firestore value only lets me get it as a Text widget and not a string

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to assign a value in a Future addMember function but am unable to retrieve an integer from another doc and assign it as a variable in this doc;

I have GetUserName, it returns a Text widget with the value I want to assign to the new document. I it does not allow me to put it directly since it's a Widget and not a value, I tried multiple method but have not had any luck.

I already tried Text().data, and get

> The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'GetUserName'.

when using .toString I get the class name to a string but not the value.

```
    TextEditingController firstName = TextEditingController()
      CollectionReference addMemberToDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Members');
      CollectionReference memberCount = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('admin');

  Future<void> addMemberFunction() {
   return addMemberToDatabase
        .doc(numId)
        .set({
'firstName': GetUserName().toString()});
```

The Example in the Firebase Docs gives:

```
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetUserName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('admin');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc("MemberCount").get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          String something = "${data['MemberCount']}";
          return Text("${data['MemberCount']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hoever, since it returns a Text and not a String then I can't use it to assign it to a variable in a new document.

Thanks in advance for any help or workaround!

Comment: Are you looking for [how to get the string from a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949107/get-the-string-content-from-a-text-widget-in-flutter)

Comment: Tried this method, and I get the following error; The getter 'text' isn't defined for the type 'Text'.
Try importing the library that defines 'text', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'text'.

Comment: You'll want to look at the **answer**, like this one that says `.data` is the property you wnat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51949194/209103